# How to transfer ssd with windows 10 to a different computer/motherboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd

My computer with windows 10 has stopped working but I still have the ssd with everything on it in my possession. I want to purchase another computer and move the ssd onto it. I understand that there is a difference between OEM and retail licenses for the windows installations. I think mine was a retail license but I don't have access to it anymore as I got the computer second-hand.

To put it briefly I want to put my current ssd with Windows 10 in it directly into another computer and I want to switch another Windows 10 license in to run on the new computer because I don't have access to the old license anymore. Is this possible?

Although I see questions similar to this all over the internet, I can't find any that address the possibility of using a new license to replace the original retail or OEM license for the Windows installation.

Comment: Any factory installed Windows is OEM so non-transferable. If you new computer comes with Windows 10 then use that. You may then use it to backup personal files and whatnot then format it and use it as additional storage, internal or external with an USB adapter, whatever is more convenient. Do not overcomplicate things that are quite simple.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for the reply. I dont

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for the reply. I don't have my new windows PC yet so I can't test this out. I'm not sure that it will be possible to just copy files from the ssd to my new computer. While I know that having physical access to hardware lets you circumvent passwords in some cases, is it just the case that you can plug in the ssd and look at the file system and copy files from it on the new computer with windows on it? There are multiple users on the windows 10 install I am trying to recover on the ssd and they have passwords. Can you just see all of their C: drives?

Comment: @John I understand the OEM and retail license deal completely. What I'm really wondering is if I can replace either one of them with a new retail license or if I will be able to view the file system and copy from it by just plugging the ssd into a new windows computer through an external adaptor, sort of like what people use to clone ssds.

Comment: Indeed, it depends. Encryption (Bitlocker) complicates the process a bit but if you know the password you can decrypt it easily. A suggestion: Setting up the new Windows with the old username and password exactly as before helps a lot but it isn't strictly necessary. I use a couple of dual-boot system where Windows is rarely used and has nothing sensitive and I can easily access everything from Ubuntu. Of course, Fast Startup is disabled.

Comment: You don't need a Windows license to boot Windows, your first and only task, should be to get the installation to boot.  Once you do that worry about changing the license key for the installation.  It's trivial to unregister a key that is being used and register the installation with another key.  **What isn't trivial is booting an installation from another device.**

Comment: Unless the two PC's are *very* similar, if not identical, the operating system in the old would not work on the new PC. Also, are you sure that the issue that killed the old PC is *not* failure of the SSD itself? *If* the SSD is working, as others suggest, just put it into the new PC as a second drive, or put it into an external SSD enclosure with USB.